# Появление погрешности на 0,0000000001 в расчётах с double числами

Tags: c#

Проблема состоит в том, что откуда-то появляется добавочная погрешность сначала на +0,00000000000001. Далее она либо ещё раз увеличивается, либо уменьшает числа при расчётах дважды на -0,00000000000001. 
В чём может быть проблема?(
Прилажу иллюстрацию и кусок кода где производятся расчёты!

```
            n1 = (int)((b - x0) / h1);
            A1 = new double[n1+1];
            x1 = new double[n1+1];
            double h2 = Math.Round(h1 / 2,3);
            n2 = (int)((b - x0) / h2);
            A2 = new double[n2+1];
            x2 = new double[n2+1];
            x1[0] = x0;
            A1[0] = y0;
            x2[0] = x0;
            A2[0] = y0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
            {
                x1[i + 1] = x1[i] + h1;
                A1[i + 1] = A1[i] + h1 * f(x1[i], A1[i]);
            }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://0.30000000000000004.com/

Comment: Ошибка стандарта вычислений IEEE 754 (http://www.softelectro.ru/ieee754.html , параграф 9  - об ошибках). Округлять нужно

Comment: понял, спасибо!!